# Get an image from a different server using jquery asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to get an image from a different server over the network using JQuery in ASP.NET?

Something like this:

```
$("#divPhotos").find("#imgMain").attr("src", "\\imageserver\images\help.JPG");
```

Comment: That isn't "getting the image" it's just setting the `src` attribute.  Does this fail in some way?  Note also that the two selectors aren't necessary, you can just do: `$("#imgMain").attr("src", "\\imageserver\images\help.JPG");`

Comment: It does not show any image, with or without the additional selector.

Comment: Is the `src` attribute updated?  Does the code execute successfully, or is there an error?  Is a network request made for the image?  Is the path valid?  Please do some debugging with your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: The image path is valid. When I try to set the src to an image on my PC, the image shows up.

Comment: What if you paste the path into the web browser address field? . Will that show the image?'... and make sure the access rights is not blocking the request

Comment: The image shows up in the web browser. And I can load the image using the FileStream method in VB also, but I want to get it through JQuery.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do here. Using \ instead of / makes me think you might be trying to load local files?